# Why Jquery not hiding my div with bootstrap classes instead working with bootstrap row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide two `div` in my html using jquery. one is working fine but other is not working.
The `div` which is working has just one class `class='row'` and the `div` which is not working has `class='p-2 d-flex pt-3'`

when i change class of this not working `div` to `row` then it works. I dont know why this is not working with other classes?

```js
$("#selOpt").change(function() {
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("value");

    if (value == 'wic') {
      $("#cus-note").hide();
      $("#cus-dues").hide();
    } else {
      $("#cus-note").show();
      $("#cus-dues").show();
    }
  });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selOpt" multiple>
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="wic">Wic</option>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
</select>

<!-- working -->
<div class="row cus-note" id="cus-note">
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control note-field" name="cust_note" value="" id="cust_note" placeholder="New Note..." required></textarea>
</div>

<!-- not working -->
<div class="p-2 d-flex pt-3" id="cus-dues">
  <div class="col-8">Dues</div>
  <div class="ml-auto" id="cust_dues"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just guessing, might have something to do with the order of the libraries/css you referred in your app

Comment: I dont think so because if that would have been a problem then one both divs shouldn't have worked. the problem is this is only working in `class ='row'` case and when i change class it doesn't.

Comment: I edited the code in your question in to a snippet where it works correctly. We can't debug an issue without seeing what causes it. As such could you please check the console in devtools in your local copy and report back any issues it lists.

Comment: `when i change class of this not working div to row then it works` this would imply it's possibly to do with CSS rule specificity. Inspect the DOM to see what classes/inline styling has been applied.

Comment: Thank you for your response @RoryMcCrossan . I just figured out the case. in second `div` i was using `d-flex` and when i checked it in bootstrap it uses `display: flex !important;` which was over-riding the .hide() function. so i managed to counter this and its working now.

Answer (score 2):

The `div` which is not working has `class='p-2 d-flex pt-3'` is actually for `d-flex` class. Because `d-flex` class having `display` property with value `flex` and it is forcing by `!important`
the css rule of `d-flex` are given bellow

```
.d-flex {
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: flex!important;
}
```

So when you trying to hide that `div` via jQuery `hide()` method it trying to add an inline css `style="display: none;"` but unfortunately it is overwritten by `display: flex!important;` that's why your `div` should not hide.

You can create a class with `display: none!important;` and add/remove this class instead of `show()/hide()`

Example of css rule:

```
html body .display-none {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Note: I create this rule by nesting html and body so that this rule can get high priority. Also, it will be better if you put this CSS at the last of your all CSS so priority will be higher.

```
$("#selOpt").change(function() {
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("value");

    if (value == 'wic') {
      $("#cus-note").addClass('display-none');
      $("#cus-dues").addClass('display-none');
    } else {
      $("#cus-note").removeClass('display-none');
      $("#cus-dues").removeClass('display-none');
    }
  });
}).change();
```

I given here the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    html body .display-none {
        display: none!important;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selOpt" multiple>
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="wic">Wic</option>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
</select>

<!-- working -->
<div class="row cus-note" id="cus-note">
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control note-field" name="cust_note" value="" id="cust_note" placeholder="New Note..." required></textarea>
</div>

<!-- not working -->
<div class="p-2 d-flex pt-3" id="cus-dues">
  <div class="col-8">Dues</div>
  <div class="ml-auto" id="cust_dues"></div>
</div>
<!--    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$("#selOpt").change(function() {
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("value");

    if (value == 'wic') {
      $("#cus-note").addClass('display-none');
      $("#cus-dues").addClass('display-none');
    } else {
      $("#cus-note").removeClass('display-none');
      $("#cus-dues").removeClass('display-none');
    }
  });
}).change();    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I just did this part and guess what, it worked. Its running perfectly.

Comment: You are most welcome and happy to hear it's running perfectly. Also, you can mark this answer as useful so that newcomers can easily get the answer.